# Delete cron jobs instead of using abort

Tags: apex, delete, scheduled-job, cron

Currently I'm using the `System.abortJob(job.Id);` method to abort the execution of already scheduled cron jobs as per the following code:

```
List<CronTrigger> cronjobList = [SELECT Id, CronJobDetail.Name FROM CronTrigger WHERE CronJobDetail.Name IN :cronJobNames];
        for (CronTrigger job : cronjobList) {
            System.abortJob(job.Id);
        }
```

I need to use DELETE query instead of invoking the `System.abortJob(job.Id);` method.

I need to know how to be able to delete scheduled cron jobs and which database tables I need to change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce doesn't expose API to delete cron job. Until now, it allows us to abortJob.

There is an idea [Ability to Modify/Delete Scheduled Apex jobs, expose CRON API](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000g9BmAAI) posted 7 years ago, you can vote on this idea.

Comment: Is it possible to delete the scheduled cron jobs directly from table `CronTrigger`? There should be a way to delete cron jobs manually by using query.

Comment: @lemdev Why do you believe this is possible? Many system objects in Salesforce are read-only.

Answer (score 1):

Today, there is a background job called "CleanupCronTriggerJob" which hard deletes these jobs which are in DELETED state and last_update > sysdate -10 (State=Deleted and are older than 10 days)

More about the process: When an Apex job (e.g. an Apex class implementing the Schedulable interface) is scheduled in Salesforce, a **CronTrigger** record is created to represent the scheduled information of a job. For scheduled jobs that run once off or have a specified finite run time, their State field is set to 'DELETED' on completion. Are these jobs automatically purged?

The answer is Yes and It is a background job called "CleanupCronTriggerJob"